# Debian 8 Jessie virtualbox vdi disk-image mount

Tags: debian, mount, virtualbox, disk-image

I need to mount virtualbox dynamic vdi image on Debian 8 system.

There is 2 ways to solve this task:

1. To use vdfuse. But it was removed from D8 repo, though it exists for D7 wheezy and I use it on wheezy. I tried to compile vdfuse from source from oracle, but it won't.
2. To use qemu-nbd. This does not work for me too. qemu-nbd mounts vdi image to /dev/nbd0 device. But thre is no partitions that could be mounted as block diveces. I suppose this is because of dynamic vdi image.

Here is the similar thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/19430/mount-a-virtualbox-drive-image-vdi and it was not helpfull for me.

On Debian 7 everithing is ok and vdfuse could be installed from repo, why it's a problem on Jessie?

Any way out?

Answer (score 2):

**PLEASE NOTE** If you already have the Debian 8 version of VirtualBox installed this may not work. If you need VirtualBox installed and working for other virtual images this may break that.

You can manually install the wheezy versions of the required packages.

Download the following `.debs` for your architecture:

- [libgsoap2](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libgsoap2)
- [virtualbox](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/virtualbox)
- [virtualbox-fuse](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/virtualbox-fuse)

Use `dpkg -i` to install them in the order they were downloaded.

Then, follow the below steps, taken from [this tutorial page](https://key-value.blogspot.com/2013/06/mounting-vhd-image-file-in-linux.html) (which is the same for a dynamic VDI, I tested both), to mount a VHD/VDI.

1. Create a mount point for the image

   ```
   # mkdir /mnt/VHD
   ```
2. Open the image file to the mount point

   ```
   # vdfuse  -w  -f  <path to vhd image>  /mnt/VHD/
   ```
3. List the contents of the vhd/vdi image

   ```
   # ls -l /mnt/VHD/
   ```

   This will show either

   ```
   EntireDisk
   ```

   or

   ```
   EntireDisk
   Partition1
       ︙
   Partitionx
   ```
4. Create mount point(s) for the extracted image(s)

   ```
   # mkdir /mnt/mydiskP1
       ︙
   # mkdir /mnt/mydiskPx
   ```
5. And mount

   ```
   # mount /mnt/VHD/Partition1 /mnt/mydiskP1
   # ls -l /mny/mydiskP1
   ```

When you are done you have to `umount` everything in reverse order

```
umount /mnt/mydiskP1
umount /mnt/VHD
```

**NOTE**
The partition layout of your image file may be different than described. If this is the case then Googling "linux mount disk image" is your friend.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.  While this tutorial may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Edited to avoid link rot. Thanks @G-Man

Answer (score 0):

1. Load nbd module

   `modprobe nbd max_part=16`
2. Map vhd to system

   `qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 image.qcow2`
3. View partition in vhd

   `fdisk -l`
4. Mount the partition you want

   `mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt`

Full step by step:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIpvNoJmVRs